# File execute permissions for automounted USB HDD (Ubuntu 11.10)

Tags: mount, ubuntu-11.10

I have an issue with Ubuntu 11.10 automounting USB HDDs where the permissions for all files on the mounted volume are set to `-rw-r--r--` and I can't change them with `chmod`.

I don't have the same issue automounting under Mint, all permissions come up as `-rwxr-xr-x`

which is what I want.

running `mount -l` from the terminal reveals that the only difference between the Ubuntu and Mint USB HDD mounts is `showexec`

So I think this is where the issue lies. I have no idea how to modify what Ubuntu does when automounting USB drives, but if I could somehow get it to include the `showexec' command line option then maybe this would fix the problem?

Possibly a modification to `/etc/fstab`?

Any pointers gratefully received.

Comment: have just signed up for a superuser account - is there a way of moving the question over? (or should I just cut and paste?)

Comment: @Hiett There is a way. Flag it as off-topic.